# Find Difference between sum of accounts within some period in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to find change in some account within some period. Assume I have several accounts and money comes and goes.
I need to find starting sum and ending sum along with difference for each unique accounts for november 2020 year.

I have a table like below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code_filial   | oper_day      |  code_account       |   sum_in           | sum_out        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00116         | 2020-05-12    | 1740100126          | 187322000          | 210522000     |
00116         | 2020-05-14    | 1740100126          | 210522000          | 256582000     |
00116         | 2020-11-04    | 1740100250          |  2000000           | 52050         |
00116         | 2020-11-05    | 1740100250          | 52050              | 2872050       |
00116         | 2020-11-14    | 1740100250          | 2872050            | 5855000       |
00116         | 2020-11-30    | 1740100250          | 5855000            | 7837000       |
00116         | 2020-12-03    | 1740100250          | 7837000            | 4900000       |
```

Result should look like below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code_filial   | oper_day      |  code_account       |   sum_in            | sum_out        | diffrence 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00116         | 2020-05-14    | 1740100126          | 256582000          | 256582000     | 256582000
00116         | 2020-11-04    | 1740100250          |    2000000         | 7837000       | 5837000
```

For example **256582000** account, in this account no process has been done in **november 2020**, so that I need to take
last **sum_out** as sum_in and sum_out, difference would be also same. But in case **1740100250** account, in this account
some operations has been done, on **2020-11-04** date,first date in november, sum_in started with **2000000** and
on last day of november **2020-11-30** sum_out was **7837000**, difference would be **7837000 - 2000000 = 5837000**.
I tried some ways but cannot make the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` and analytical function with `KEEP` clause as follows (Please note that I have not tested it. Just created query as per the requirement. You need to solve few errors if there are any)

```
select code_filal, code_account, oper_day, sum_in, sum_out,
       case when is_entry_nov_exists > 0 then sum_out-sum_in else sum_out end as difference
from
(select code_filal, code_account, is_entry_nov_exists,
        case when is_entry_nov_exists > 0 
             then min(case when oper_day >= date '2020-11-01' and oper_day < date '2020-12-01' 
                           then oper_day end)
             else max(oper_day) 
        end as oper_day,
        case when is_entry_nov_exists > 0 
             then max(case when oper_day >= date '2020-11-01' then sum_in end) 
                  keep (dense_rank first order by oper_day)
             else max(sum_out) 
                  keep (dense_rank last order by oper_day) 
        end as sum_in,
        case when is_entry_nov_exists > 0 
             then max(case when oper_day >= date '2020-11-01' then sum_out end) 
                  keep (dense_rank last order by oper_day)
             else max(sum_out) 
                  keep (dense_rank last order by oper_day) 
        end as sum_out
 from
(select t.*, 
        count(case when oper_day >= date '2020-11-01' and oper_day < date '2020-12-01' 
                   then 1 
              end) 
           OVER (partition by code_filial, code_account) as is_entry_nov_exists
  from your_table t 
 where oper_day < date '2020-12-01') t
group by code_filal, code_account, is_entry_nov_exists) t
```

Comment: ```select t.*, count( .. ``` part is now working since count does not work without group by. How can I solve this?

Comment: Ohh Yes, Code is updated. Please check now.